# AEM Eclipse plugin - New project creation issue

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, adobe, aem

I have installed AEM Eclipse plugin from https://eclipse.adobe.com/aem/dev-tools (I downloaded it as archive and used in my Eclipse as local archive).

Then I faced issue with AEM wizard not showing up while creating new project. Found workaround to download the archetype catalog xml file from https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/archetype-catalog.xml and add it to Eclipse (Maven) as local archetype catalog. It started showing the AEM project when creating new project. I can see 3 archetypes in the dialog that opens after selecting New - AEM - AEM Sample Multi-Module Project.

I can see com.adobe.granite.archetypes:sample-project-archetype with 5, 6 and 7 versions. When I select version **7 (or even 5 and 6)** and click on next button, it does **not** show the maven configuration dialog but stays on the same archetype selection dialog. When I click one more time, I can see the title of the dialog changes to **"This step defines which server to use with the new project."** but there are no options to select the server. In the eclipse log, I can see the error: **"Unhandled event loop exception"** and stack trace

*java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not process archetype: null
    at com.adobe.granite.ide.eclipse.ui.wizards.np.AdvancedSettingsComponent.initialize(AdvancedSettingsComponent.java:267)
    at com.adobe.granite.ide.eclipse.ui.wizards.np.SimplerParametersWizardPage.setVisible(SimplerParametersWizardPage.java:160) ....*

I have tried several options of changing the proxy settings, using externally installed maven and also trying to download the archetype jar separately from the server as suggested on some sites. But not able to make it work.

Any help would be appreciated.

I am using: **Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Kepler Release Build id: 20130614-0229
Maven: apache-maven-3.1.1**

Comment: Can you post a complete stack trace? Also, it would be good to try with the latest version of the plugin

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and now i solved it. It seems the repository url in archetype catalog is not accessible. in my case it was proxy settings for https, which i set in settings.xml
as a check try to install the project from command line to see more information:

> mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=de.test -DartifactId=testAEM -DarchetypeArtifactId=sample-project-archetype -DarchetypeGroupId=com.adobe.granite.archetypes -DarchetypeVersion=7 -DarchetypeCatalog=file://[path to aem archetype file]/archetype-catalog.xml -DinteractiveMode=true

Hope it helps

Comment: @irkhin Could you please tell me proxy settings configuration that you set. I am facing "no plugin found for prefix 'archetype' " in the current project